# How to modify(move) points in cgal Dd Delaunay Triangulations

Tags: c++, cgal

I need to take a given Dd CGAL Delaunay triangulation and modify the point coordinates.

The original triangulation or point-->cell assignment must remain intact and I do not care whether the resulting triangulation is still a valid Delaunay triangulation.

Naively one would think that iterating over the cells and vertices and then doing something like

```
for(int dimension=0; d<dim; d++)
   vertex->point()[dimension] = new_coordinate_value
   //note, that vertex->data()=new_value would work!
```

would do the job, but the point() result appears to be read-only.

Is there a simple way to implement the operation I need?

Sidenote:
A (tedious and not preferred, but possible with the tools i have at hand) way to circumvent this, would be to use the data member of the vertex to store a reference to "my actual coordinates", modify those when needed and only use those coordinates for any further calculations.

Comment: `vertex->set_point(...)`? https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation/classTriangulationVertex.html#af5e882055936c00e2a80a9dbf74ed0ac

Comment: Thank you - the solution is indeed as simple as you suggest. For some reason i did not find this option with google and failed to notice it during a short cgal manual research.